# Why do the neuron pathways decussate?

Tags: evolution, neuroscience, brain

I learn about the brain right now, and there are crossing of neuron pathways everywhere; in the thalamus, the medulla oblongata, the pyramidal tract... And I don't understand why? What is the reason to connect - for example - the right foot to the left part of your brain?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/why-is-most-life-symmetrical-externally-but-not-internally/5601#5601) and especially [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/why-do-the-two-hemispheres-of-the-brain-control-the-opposite-sides-of-the-body/3835#3835).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crossing or decussation is a lot more robust against wiring errors than their seemingly simpler same-sided wiring counterparts. See [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ar.20731/pdf) for the research carried out to establish this and for more detail.